# Shell Script) How can i pass parameters to expect script?

Tags: shell, expect

Now I'm making a shell script with expect to send a file to sftp server.
But when i pass a filepath to shell script, there is an empty file path parameter when use 'put' command. (also get or put)

How can I pass parameters to get or put command?

There is a code below.

```
set FILEPATH [lindex $argv 0]
expect << EOL
sleep 3
spawn sftp id@sftp_ip
expect "password:"
send "mypassword\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /remote/directory\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "get $FILEPATH\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
interact
```

Comment: `set FILEPATH [lindex $argv 0]` looks like a tcl command, not a shell command, and thus should probably inside the expect script (Which would need to be run with the appropriate pathname as an argument)

Comment: @sssrigo : Shawn is right. What is the point in writing Tcl commands **outside** of your _expect_ code. But as to your question, one other possibility to pass data into your Tcl/expect program is to place it in the environment, which can then be retrieved inside Tcl via `$env(VARNAME)`

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.